# How to Create index on component property

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, sql-server-ce

I have the following classes:

```
public class Event
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual EventId EventId { get; set; }
}

public class EventId 
{
    public virtual Guid EventGuid {get; private set;}
}
```

I am using a fluent NHibernate automapping in order to map my classes and I override specific properties when needed.

Class: Event is in s_typesToMap and class: EventId is in s_components.

As a result I get the following table generated:

```
create table "Event" (
   Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER not null,
   UserName NVARCHAR(255) null,
   EventIdentifierEventGuid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER null,
   primary key (Id)
)
```

I want to create an index on EventIdentifierEventGuid which is a property in Event component.

I tried to do it as follows:

```
.Override<Event>(obj => obj.Map(x => x.EventId.EventGuid).Index("EventId_index"))
```

When I generate the ddl I get the following:

```
create index EventId_index on "Event" (EventGuid)
```

The expected result should be an index on EventIdentifierEventGuid instead of EventGuid

How can I do it?